# how to get time spent in I/O operation in hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, mapr

I am running a hive query which involves joins. I can see 'CPU time spent (ms)' from map reduce counters using resource manager UI. How can I see, time spent in input output operation?

Is there any open source tool that I can use for the same? Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: hive by default gives you the processing time for queries in hive-shell.

Comment: Yes, I know that and that is not my question. I need to know time spend during IO operation.